# Base access to DynamoDB Records off of a attribute in a record

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I am looking to limit access to my dynamodb records based off of an attribute in a table.  From the documentation I read, there does not seem to be a straightforward way to do this unless I have made a huge error.  Here is an example of what I would like to accomplish:

```
Table 1
userid
groups <-- (a list of groupids that the user belongs to)


Table 2
groupid
data
someotherdata
```

I would like the user in Table 1 to be able to have full access to the information in table 2.  Is this possible via dynamodb?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manage your groups in [IAM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html), you can set a [fine-grained access control](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/fine-grained-access-control-for-amazon-dynamodb/) policy on Table 1 that can restrict the visibility and access to items and attributes in items to particular groups.